# Why do I have to hate hats in order to opt out of Winter Bash?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, winter-bash, wording

Why are you, the ever so pink-and-fluffy SE making me hate ?

I don't hate hats. I just don't want to participate because I'm a grumpy old bahumbug kinda guy.

I don't like hating :(

Can we choose not to participate rather than having to hate ?

I am sad.

Comment: Maybe because "I prefer to not participate in Winter Bash this year, thank you very much and have a good time" is bit too long and formal? It's all about fun. You can either love it, or hate it. Or ignore it. :-)

Comment: @lain: Would you be willing to edit your question, focusing on changing the label, instead of on the 'hate' part and noise that I think is currently included in this question? That way I wouldn't mind (anymore) if my earlier question from today would be marked as duplicate.

Answer (score 35):

You're misunderstanding this. "Hate" here does not refer to the verb for "extreme and hostile dislike"; it's a short form of "**hat e**rasure". The etymology is explained in [this episode](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SQoA_wjmE9w) of the "History of Words" podcast.

Comment: "I hat erasure hats"? That doesn't sound right. But the fine folks at [english.se] would probably know better.

Comment: Feature request: change to "I ate hats".

Comment: I'm still sad. I don't like hating however you wish to try and wriggle out of it.

Comment: I followed the link, I am sadder.

Comment: like in the song, What does the Fox Say?  Hate Hate Hate Ho

Comment: @balpha: I think YOU misunderstand this (or should I rather say "seem to not be willing to listen ..."?

Answer (score 12):

The choice of words might be glib to the original author of the dialog box, but it really does [bother some of us](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/4151).  It's not simply being sensitive about a “bad word” used by someone else. Rather, it's asking us to *make a statement* about ourselves, using a word (concept) that we remind ourselves **not to do**.

Maybe we need to get a card-carrying Buddist or somesuch in here to officially make it a religous issue?

What’s your good solid UX reason for *not* rephrasing it to simply state the effect of the choice?

Comment: The wording has now changed from "I hate hats" to "No hats for me, please": see my answer below.

Answer (score 10):

Please review [Replace text in website with Chrome content script extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5797661/replace-text-in-website-with-chrome-content-script-extension) to create an extension that replaces every instance of *"I hate hats"* to a phrase of your choice, such as, *"Don't show hats - it's not you, it's me, maybe we can just be friends.  Friends that never, ever see each other."*

Comment: If you want something simpler, use an existing word replacer extension, such as https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/word-replacer-ii/djakfbefalbkkdgnhkkdiihelkjdpbfh?hl=en and once installed you can create whole lists of corrections for phrase you don't want to see on the internet.

Comment: Please enhance your question to explain what to do for those who don't HAVE (for whatever reason) or HATE (oeps: DO NOT LIKE ...) Chrome?

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens Each browser has its own method to incorporate userscripts and extensions.  I'm not going to write a comprehensive guide here, those who are curious might want to refer to http://www.mturkgrind.com/threads/which-browsers-can-you-run-userscripts-in-and-how.27432/ and use google to search phrases such as *"[mybrowser] script replace words"* for clues as to how to proceed.  Alternately employ someone else to click the link for you, then ignore it altogether for a few weeks if you can't bring yourself to click a link with the word "hate" in it.

Comment: Merci for the clarification.

Answer (score 8):

Simple, concise replacement that should work well for everyone:

> No hats for me!

It's only a little longer than the original (unlike some of the unwieldy monstrosities being thrown about) and gets to the point without being painfully drab as e.g. "Don't show hats" would be.

Comment: An even simpler No Thanks would be better.

Comment: @Iain: The opt-out link is shown at the bottom of the hat popdown, so "No thanks" wouldn't fit there.

Answer (score 7):

As of Winter Bash 2020, this has changed from being [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) to [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed).

The button to opt out of hats now says "No hats for me, please" instead of "I hate hats":

[image: No hats for me, please]

So now you no longer have to express hate for hats in order to opt out of them.

Answer (score 4):

Would be nice if "I hate hats" would changed to "I do not like hats" ... But I fear this suggestion may only makes sense for those who are living around Paris or Brussels.

PS 1: this answer is only about the terrible label, not about if one should yes/no participate.

PS 2: refer to my "related" feature request at "[Change "I hate hats" to an opt-in approach on ALL sites (not only on SO)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271176)" ... Which IMHO is not a duplicate. If it ever gets implemented, it'd also address the this question ... I think.

Answer (score -1):

I think, but am absolutely not sure, it is 'spoken' (typed) in a [Grumpy](http://disney.wikia.com/wiki/Grumpy) manner: "I hate {x}".

Meaning that you don't actually hate it, but don't want to show your affection for it either.

Comment: When I was "forced" to indicate "I do not like hats", I was NOT grumpy. So this answer does not apply in all cases.